# Add column with default including newlines

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write add a column to a table in SQLITE with a default string, which includes newline characters. I was under the impression that the following should work:

```
-- x'0a' is the literal for a new line
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD mailfooter TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'With best regards' || x'0a' || 'Superdupa Company';
```

in order to produce the following column content:

```
With best regards
Superdupa Company
```

This though gives the following error: `near "||": syntax error`

I then tried adding parenthesis around the DEFAULT value like this:

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD mailfooter TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ('With best regards' || x'0a' || 'Superdupa Company');
```

Now the error is the following: `Cannot add a column with non-constant default`

Interestingly both variants work when used in a select statement:

```
SELECT 'With best regards' || x'0a' || 'Superdupa Company';
```

or

```
SELECT ('With best regards' || x'0a' || 'Superdupa Company');
```

both produce the expected result without errors.

How do I add a column with a linebreak in the default value?

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_default_clause) it sounds like the second one should work...

Comment: @HoneyBadger using `0x0a` produces the same result as I described in the question, as does `char(10)`. Also removing the newline, i.e. using `'With best regards' || 'Superdupa Company'` as the DEFAULT clause gives the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis around the `DEFAULT` expression are a mandatory part of the syntax.

This works for me:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(bar, baz NOT NULL DEFAULT ('some' || char(0x0A) || 'text'));
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(1);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
bar  baz
---  ---------
1    some
text
```

as does using a blob literal in the expression like you tried (`('some' || x'0A' || 'text')`).

Using `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...` with the same constraint fails for me on Sqlite 3.35.5, but works on Sqlite 3.38.5. I don't see anything in the change log between the two versions that directly references this, but apparently something changed in between to make the validity-checking of `ALTER TABLE` more in line with `CREATE TABLE`.

So, update to the latest Sqlite release and you should be okay.

Comment: And *now* it's working on 3.35.5. Exact same commands that were giving an error still visible in my terminal's scroll buffer. Bizarre.

Comment: Very interesting. I can confirm that it works on 3.38.5 for me as well, and that it doesn't work on 3.31.1 (the default in Ubuntu 20.04).